# Generating sitemap.xml in tapestry

Tags: java, xml, sitemap, tapestry

I am using tapestry (java framework) and I am trying to generate a sitemap.xml file. I need to create it dynamically and then return it as StreamResponse. I have the sitemapgen4j-1.0.1 library, but the library requires a path where the sitemap.xml should be written and that's something I don't want. Is there any way to use this library w/o writing the xml file?
Also do I need to manually add every single link to the sitemap (using sitemapgen4j addUrl() method)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, no, there is not. You would need to fork sitemapgen4j and make it write to an `OutputStream` or `Writer`.

If you'd rather like to use the library as-is, you could create a temporary file (via [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))), pass that to sitemapgen4j, use it in your StreamResponse, and delete it after you're done reading.